# I'm trying to identify a literary device in formal rhetoric

Tags: rhetoric

Plainly put, I am writing a commentary on the book of Galatians, while employing a socio-rhetorical analysis.

The writer introduces himself as an Apostle, establishing his authority, and concludes with reprimanding "false apostles".

The ideas are juxtaposed, being separated by a large number of juxtaposing words, concepts, and allusions. (Flesh and spirit, life and death, Hebrew and Greek, male and female etc.)

I am attempting establish that the document as a whole begins and ends with opposing concepts that are only separated by the repeated use of the same rhetorical devices applied to the beginning and ending of the letter.

In doing this, the writer has persuaded the reader to accept the introductory and concluding statements, which are quite contrary to one another, by using similarly contrasting phrases between the two opposing ideas.

I'm hoping there is a definitive term to apply to this technique.

I'm trying to be as clear as possible. I would like to identify the arrangement as a whole. The construction appears to be what I can only define as an "expanded juxtaposition", at least, abstractly speaking.

I've never seen such a mode of persuasion used in any other literature. Is there a technical term for this type of argument, or have I stumbled across something that needs defining?

Answer (score 1):

A starting point for research could be in the term "cognitive dissonance." Defined from [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognitive%20dissonance):

> psychological conflict resulting from incongruous beliefs and attitudes held simultaneously

This term doesn't describe the style of argument, but it does, possibly, describe the results of the Galatians Apostle's argument.

A second idea: during my English class while earning my Bachelor's degree, I had a professor who used "diptych" in a literary manner. Again [from Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diptych):

> 1: a 2-leaved hinged tablet folding together to protect writing on its waxed surfaces
>   2 : a picture or series of pictures (such as an altarpiece) painted or carved on two hinged tablets
>   3 : a work made up of two matching parts

The way my professor used "diptych" most aligns with definition 3) -- the professor used the term to describe two figures, characters, places or things, which were similar in some way, yet were also distinctly different. Putting the two figures into comparison with each other was a "diptych," and through analysis of it, new insights could be gained. Perhaps this will assist?